# Docker DDEV / DB error | php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: database, docker, windows

I'm quite new to the Docker and DDEV material.
I've setup a local instance of our Magento repository, using Docker and DDEV.
Imported the database and changed the env.php using the following settings for the DB:
[image: env db settings]

But I keep getting the following error when I try to run bin/magento setup:upgrade

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql
> failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

I also tried to run the command from inside the container, by first getting into the container using `docker exec -ti ddev-containername-web bash`, but the same result unfortunately.

It seems that there is something wrong with the connection between the Magento install and the db, but I can't find what it is.

My environment:

- Windows 11
- WSL2 (Ubuntu)
- Docker Desktop